# exception: can't temprelease nested lock

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run some server-side JS in Mongo. Operations I am trying to perform are:

```
db.dropDatabase();   // removing current database
db.copyDatabase('db_dump', 'db', 'localhost');  // substituting it with a dump
```

Everything works perfectly nice. When I am storing this as a function:

```
function () {
    db.dropDatabase();
    return db.copyDatabase('db_dump', 'db', 'localhost');
}
```

and executing it, everything is also nice and returns me `{"ok" : 1}`

But when I try to execute this using php driver:

```
$db->execute("function(){ db.dropDatabase(); return db.copyDatabase('db_dump', 'db', 'localhost'); }");
```

I get

```
{
    "retval": {
        "errmsg":"exception: can't temprelease nested lock",
        "code":10298,
        "ok":0
    },
    "ok":1
}
```

My first though was that I just need to get out of the lock, so I tried this

```
$db->command(
    array(
        '$eval' => "function() { db.dropDatabase(); return db.copyDatabase('db_dump', 'db', 'localhost');}"
    ),
    array(
        'nolock'=> true
    )
);
```

Nothing else is using database at this point.

Any ideas how to get rid of this error?

I am using `Mongo 2.4.4`, `PHP 5.3.13` and `driver 1.2.10`
P.S. Tried this on `PHP 5.4.16` and the situation is the same

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/GGLqwEsJwVg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command cannot be invoked through the [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) command (see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/GGLqwEsJwVg/-6rlm6MZqUsJ) for some additional discussion on the matter). Rather than use JS methods, you can invoke the [copydb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/) command directly with [MongoDB::command()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php). The following script will copy between two databases on the same server, since I omitted the `fromhost` option:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$m->a->drop();
$m->admin->command([
  'copydb' => 1,
  'fromdb' => 'b',
  'todb' => 'a',
]);
```